# How to fix the pause button?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter, python-vlc

I made a program that allows you to choose any audio to play using vlc module and tkinter.

The pause button didn't work.
Even using global variable it didn't work.

```
#define "select file" function
def select_file():
    global filename
    filetypes = (
        ('MP3 files', '*.mp3'),)

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Select audio', initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)

#define "play audio" function
def play():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
    p.play()
#define "pause audio" function
def pause():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
    p.stop()

#open button
open_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1, text="Select file", command=select_file)
open_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

#play button
play_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1, text="Play", command=play)
play_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

#pause button
pause_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1, text="Pause", command=pause)
pause_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
```

Comment: __what__ didn't work exactly? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @Julien The pause button if you read the code carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `pause()`, you need to use the instance of `vlc.MediaPlayer()` created inside `play()` instead of creating a new one.

I would suggest to create the instance once outside the functions:

```py
# create the player once
player = vlc.MediaPlayer()

#define "select file" function
def select_file():
    global filename
    filetypes = (
        ('MP3 files', '*.mp3'),)

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Select audio', initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)

    if filename:
        # set the song to play
        player.set_mrl(filename)

#define "play audio" function
def play():
    player.play()

#define "pause audio" function
def pause():
    player.pause()  # use .pause() instead of .stop()
```